# Using named ranges as subroutine arguments in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, arguments, range, subroutine

I wanted a subroutine to append a specified row from one named range to the bottom of another named range and could not find any references to a method. After a couple of goes I came up with the following. There may be built in functions that do this if you know where to find them, but this code worked for me.

' ==== Append a specified row "Ix" from one named range "Rsource" to the bottom of another named range "Rdestination" ====
' The number of values copied is the lesser of the number of columns in the 2 ranges

```
Public Sub AppendTuple(Rsource As String, Rdestination As String, Ix As Long)

Dim I As Long, J As Long, Ar As Long, K As Long

' --- how many values to copy
If Range(Rsource).Columns.Count <= Range(Rdestination).Columns.Count Then 
    I = Range(Rsource).Columns.Count
Else
    I = Range(Rdestination).Columns.Count
End If

' --- add a row to Range(Rdestination)
Ar = Range(Rdestination).Rows.Count + 1                     
Range(Rdestination).Resize(Ar).Name = Rdestination

' --- copy/paste  the data to the new row 
For J = 1 To I                                              
    Range(Rdestination).Cells(Ar, J) = Range(Rsource).Cells(Ix, J)
Next
End Sub
```

This was tested using a button on a userform to call the above. The two ranges named "InRow" (12 by 6) and "OutRow"(1 by 4) where created manually.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim Ir As Long
Ir = Int((12) * Rnd + 1)               ' random integer between 1 and 12
Call AppendTuple("InRow", "OutRow", Ir)
End Sub
```

Comment: When the code was posted the comments and lines of code were concatenated with the following line of code.

Comment: Not sure what your query is? is there an issue with your code? Or are you asking if there is another way to do what your code does?. I suspect it's the later